# Airflow reads task job_name parameter as a folder

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to run a DAG using a custom Operator for a task, but the `job_name` parameter(set automatically to be the same as the `task_id` name) is being read as a folder structure instead of the string itself. Example: `"example_task"` is being read as `"\example_task\"`. By default, Airflow does not accept the `"\"` character in `job_name`.

Here is the code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datamechanics_airflow_plugin.operator import DataMechanicsOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
import pendulum


local_tz = pendulum.timezone("America/Sao_Paulo")

with DAG(
    dag_id="processing_dag",
    start_date=days_ago(1).astimezone(tz=local_tz),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
) as dag:

    start = DummyOperator(task_id="start")

    end=DummyOperator(task_id="end")

    landing_to_processing=DataMechanicsOperator(
            task_id="landing_to_processing",
            config_template_name="spark-gcp-hudi",
            config_overrides={
                "mainApplicationFile": "/home/edu/airflow/dags/scripts/process_landing_data.py",
                },
            )

start>>landing_to_processing>>end
```

The DataMechanicsOperator comes from https://www.datamechanics.co/ and the plugin has been correctly installed.

Here is part of the Airflow UI error message:

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Response: b'{"errors": {"jobName": "\'landing_to_processing\' does not match \'^[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*$\'"}, "message": "Input payload validation failed"}\n', Status Code: 400
```

I've tested the code in a local Airflow Server and in a Docker container.

I really can't see what could be possibly causing this.

Comment: It's impossible to help you without seeing the operator code. Please post the operator code

Comment: what happens if you add `job_name="landing_to_processing"` to the operator?

Comment: I got it. The job_name in this case should be a valid k8's string and underscores are not allowed. Here is the operator repo: https://github.com/datamechanics/datamechanics_airflow_plugin